# formatting toString method using String.format

Tags: java, tostring, string.format

required output: 
Code: 123          Title: BookA          Fees(SGD): $20.00
                   Loan Duration: 3 wks

```
return String.format("%-20s%-20s%\n", "Code: " + code, "Title: " + title, "%.2f\nFees(SGD): $" + fees, "Lesson Duration: " + lessonDuration + "wks");
```

it only returns only the first 3 (code, title, fees) but not loan duration. also where do i put in %.2f for fees so that it will always be of 2 decimal place?

Comment: Is the language Java? Please tag it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question asks about "Loan Duration", but your example code uses "Lesson Duration".  That could be your problem.

That %.2f should work for setting two decimal places.  How is it behaving?

Comment: sorry for that typo. problem is the last part duration wasnt even printed out. it stops after printing fees. where should i put the %.2f ?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `String.format`, you usually just pass your variables in and use the correct percent signs for your variables' types. For instance, if you want to format an integer, you use `%d`: `String.format("Here is an integer: %d", myInt)`. For strings, you use `%s`, and for doubles, you use `%f` (with `.2` to indicate the number of decimal places as you've already found out. You put *all* of your formatting in the first string parameter. All you have to do then is this:

```java
String code = "123";
String title = "BookA";
double fees = 20.943;
int lessonDuration = 3;

String str = String.format("Code: %s\nTitle: %s\nFees(SGD): $%.2f\nLesson Duration: %d wks", 
    code, 
    title, 
    fees, 
    lessonDuration);
```

You should go [read this article here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) so you understand formatting in Java and don't fail your test.